# Why for-in loop doesn't print what I want?

Tags: bash, for-loop

I wrote in the terminal:

```
arr=(1 2 3)
for x in $arr; do
 echo $x
done
```

and it just prints '1'.
Why doesn't it print 1 2 3 ?

Comment: Try `echo $arr` for further enlightenment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
for x in $arr; do
```

to

```
for x in "${arr[@]}"; do
```

Answer (score 1):

To expand to all the elements of an array, use `"${arr[@]}"`

```
for x in "${arr[@]}"; do
```

When you use the array name as an ordinary variable, without indexing it, it expands to the first element.